# maven package war missing dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

when I start learning spring boot,I made a project springboot-demo as the root, an three modules admin-service、common-service and dao.

this is root pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>springboot-demo</name>
    <modules>
        <module>admin-service</module>
        <module>common-service</module>
        <module>dao</module>
    </modules>
    <groupId>cc.xiaoerbi</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mybatis-spring-boot>1.2.0</mybatis-spring-boot>
        <mysql-connector>5.1.39</mysql-connector>
    </properties>
</project>
```

this is the admin pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>cc.xiaoerbi</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>admin-service</name>
    <artifactId>admin-service</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cc.xiaoerbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Web  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is the dao pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>cc.xiaoerbi</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>dao</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Mybatis  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis-spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.30</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I package admin war failed
told：

> [WARNING] The POM for cc.xiaoerbi:dao:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

I've written some similar code, and it work. I don't know what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

change your module so that you compile your dependecies before using them.

```
<modules>
    <module>dao</module>
    <module>admin-service</module>
    <module>common-service</module>
</modules>
```

The folder names that contain the dao, admin-service, and common-service pom.xml shold be in the root folder and they should match the modules names in the root pom.xml.  Also, you should run the "mvn clean install" compile from the root directory and not the admin directory.  If you compile from admin, it will not compile dao first.  It will try to pull in from the repo when it cannot find a resource in the ~/.m2/repositoy local cache.

Add the

```
<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

to the admin-service and common-service.

They talk about it in Project Inheritance section example 2 on https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: Added more instruction and structure that could cause that error to come up.